# Trying to order by multiple columns, want only the values of a column that has more than one value

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT n.title, n.language, n.nid, nr.hash
FROM `node` n
LEFT JOIN `node_revision` nr ON (nr.title = n.title)
group by n.title having count(*) > 1
order by n.title, n.language, n.nid ASC
```

I am trying to sort in order of title, language, and nid from the node table.

However, I only want titles where at least 2 or more exist.

This query looks like it should do it, but instead I'm only getting unique results, which is not what I want.

How do I sort by all of these columns, while only getting titles where the exact same title exists in more than one row?

The duplicate titles are in the node table.

Comment: What is causing the duplicates?  `node_revision` or could there be duplicates in `node`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT n.title, n.language, n.nid, nr.hash
    FROM node n
    LEFT JOIN node_revision nr ON (nr.title = n.title)
    and n.title in 
    (SELECT n.title FROM node n group by n.title having count(*) > 1)
    order by n.title, n.language, n.nid ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the duplicates are due to the `node_revision` table:

```
SELECT n.title, n.language, n.nid, nr.hash
FROM `node` n join
     `node_revision` nr
      ON nr.title = n.title join
      (select nr.title, count(*) as cnt
       from node_revision nr
       group by nr.title
      ) nrcnt
      on nrcnt.title = n.title and cnt > 1
order by n.title, n.language, n.nid ASC;
```

I also switched the `join` to an inner join.  It seems odd to look for duplicates using an outer join, but it could be reasonable if the duplicates could be in either table.

If the duplicates could be in either table, then you just need to do the join in the subquery:

```
SELECT n.title, n.language, n.nid, nr.hash
FROM `node` n left join
     `node_revision` nr
      ON nr.title = n.title left join
      (select nr.title, count(*) as cnt
       from node n left join
            node_revision nr
            on n.title = tr.title
       group by nr.title
      ) nrcnt
      on nrcnt.title = n.title and cnt > 1
order by n.title, n.language, n.nid ASC;
```